# Filter Multiple Fields, Select List Row, then Update List

Tags: list, spservices

I have a SP 2010 list which I need to filter (with AJAX) based on multiple user requirements (dates, number of attendees, room requirements, etc), each corresponding to separate columns. Next, allow the user to select a remaining row which they want, and give them an option to select and update that row.

I am using SP Services to do the filtering, but only with a single criteria at the moment, but I do not know the best strategy to accomplish the rest of what I am trying to achieve here.

Below is the code I have for the filtering I have in place atm:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: true,
    debug: true,
    listName: "Available_Rooms",
    maxResults: 11,
    CAMLRowLimit: 11,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

        var JsonObject = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').SPXmlToJson({
                mapping: {
                    ows_RoomCapacity: { mappedName: "RoomCapacity", objectType: "Number" }
                },
                includeAllAttrs: true,
                removeOws: true,
                sparse: true 
            });

$('#VTCAvailableRooms').dataTable({
    "pageLength": 11,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bLoadingRecords": 'Please wait - loading...',
    "bFilter": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    "responsive": true, 
    "aaData": JsonObject,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "mData": "RoomCapacity", "aTargets":  [ 0 ] },
        { "mData": "DisplayName", "aTargets":  [ 1 ] },
        { "mData": "RoomDeptOwner", "aTargets":  [ 2 ] },
        { "mData": "RoomType", "aTargets":  [ 3 ] },
        { "mData": "Title", "aTargets":  [ 4 ] },
        { "mData": "VTC", "aTargets":  [ 5 ] },
        { "mData": "Projector", "aTargets":  [ 6 ] }
    ]
});
    }
});
```

});

I'm not asking for someone to solve my problem for me, but I'd love it if they could point me in the right direction or recommend some tools I could use to solve this that would be amazing! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SPServices you can specify a `CAMLQuery` parameter (see options listed for the `GetListItems` method [here](https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/core/web-services/Lists.html)), and build your query based on your criteria.

Example:
`CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Active</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"`

If you need help building your CAML, there's a good utility called CAMLQueryHelper ([CodePlex](https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/); [GitHub](https://github.com/bandrben/SPCAMLQueryHelperOnline)).

However, even Marc (the author) will tell you things are going toward REST (SPServices uses SOAP), so if you have the opportunity to do so, I would suggest giving making a REST query a shot here, via the `_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Your List Name')/Items?$filter=` method. You can see more about OData operations (like `$filter`) [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests).